# Example from Socket.IO 1.4.3 docs gives error

Tags: node.js, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

I've been trying to execute this simple first example from Socket.IO documentation which doesn't seem to work in any way I have tried.

Here is my code:

```
var io = require('socket.io');
io.listen(server);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

And following is the error log:

```
/home/chetan/project/app.js:70
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
   ^
TypeError: Object function Server(srv, opts){
  if (!(this instanceof Server)) return new Server(srv, opts);
  if ('object' == typeof srv && !srv.listen) {
    opts = srv;
    srv = null;
  }
  opts = opts || {};
  this.nsps = {};
  this.path(opts.path || '/socket.io');
  this.serveClient(false !== opts.serveClient);
  this.adapter(opts.adapter || Adapter);
  this.origins(opts.origins || '*:*');
  this.sockets = this.of('/');
  if (srv) this.attach(srv, opts);
} has no method 'on'
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/chetan/project/app.js:70:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
```

I've been staring at the logs for a couple of minutes but can't seem to understand what's wrong.

I even tried using it this way:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Which generates the following error:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
           ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'on' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/chetan/project/app.js:70:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
```

What do you think could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved the problem by browsing the web a little.

I just figured out that the design pattern that I'm using is different from theirs. When socket.io listens to a server it returns an object which must be used for communication.

Here is a working piece of code for example:

```
var io = require('socket.io');
var websocket = io.listen(server);

websocket.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Additionally, you can use the following way to code the logic of your websocket server in a separate file. Assuming the filename is websocketProcessor.js, here is the code:

```
var io = require('socket.io');
var websocket = io.listen(server);

require('./websocketProcessor')(websocket);
```